# Need help in writing script for indicator

Tags: pine-script

I am new at scripting dont know how to write properly,Can anybody help me with script for below logic:

- Take difference between previous day 10SMA(Day candle) high and open
- Take difference between previous day 10SMA(Day candle) low and open
- Whichever value is less from above two add to today open.(plot on chart)
- Whichever value is less from first two less from today open.(plot on chart)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where exactly do you need help? Show us what you have tried. Do you want us to write the code for you?

Comment: Hello Baris,I am very beginer in scripting still after refering to help and other reference scripts i was able to write below code but not able to plot on chart.

//vesrion=3
study("SMA OB")
SMAhigh =  sma(high,10)
SMAlow = sma(low,10)
SMAopen = sma(open,10)
Diff = SMAhigh - SMAopen
Diff1= SMAopen - SMAlow

if Diff>Diff1
Plotshape()

Comment: I would suggest you read this tutorial: https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Pine_Script_Tutorial